# Is anybody using Amazon Kinesis in production, what are the experiences and what was the rationale for choosing this service?

Tags: amazon-web-services

[Amazon Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) could be used to analyze streaming data. I wonder whether anybody is using this service and what are the experiences? After reading this documentation I have no idea for what purposes this service could be used.

Comment: I am not using it but it looks to me like it could be Amazon's vision of Kafka: https://medium.com/@shastri.shankar9/apache-kafka-vs-amazon-kinesis-b55821c7f51f
The company's policy is to own important assets like they abandoned third-party RDBMS by own products.